# How to make automatic creation of a single instance of the class at startup application

Tags: php, laravel

I have class with my logic.

class BlogApp

```
   class BlogApp
   {
    public static $app;

    public function __construct()
    {
        self::$app = Registry::instance();
        $this->getParams();
    }
```

class Registry

```
   class Registry
   {
    use TSingletone;

    protected static $properties = [];

    public function setProperty($name, $value)
    {
        self::$properties[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function getProperty($name)
    {
        if (isset(self::$properties[$name])) {
            return self::$properties[$name];
        }
        return null;
    }

    public function getProperties()
    {
        return self::$properties;
    }
```

I want to use my class BlogApp { } anywhere in the controllers to store properties. For example

```
    BlogApp::$app->setProperty('img_width', 1280);

    $wmax = BlogApp::$app->getProperty('img_width');
```

and my public/index.php

```
    new \App\BlogApp();
```

but I have exception

```
    Call to a member function getProperty() on null
```

if I use this one

```
    $d = new BlogApp();
    $d::$app->getProperty('img_width');
```

No problem. But I want

```
   $wmax = BlogApp::$app->getProperty('img_width');
```

where is my mistake ?

Comment: Why not just use the container provided by Laravel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating an object of the Registry within constructor in BlogApp class, so to call the getProperty method, you have to need to create an object of BlogApp.

However, if you want to call the getProperty function with a reference to the class, then don't create an instance of Registry in the BlogApp constructor.

```php
class BlogApp
{
    public static $app;

    // Create a function call get_instance 
    public static function get_instance()
    {
        // create instance of Registry class
        self::$app = Registry::instance();
        self::getParams();

        return self::$app;
    }
}

/*
* Call the getProperty funtion with reference of class.
* 1 - Object of the Registry is Creating When you call the static function get_instance.
* 2 - Once the object is created you can call the getProperty function.
*/
$wmax = BlogApp::get_instance()->getProperty('img_width');
```

Comment: Thx ! Its works !   only added this one - self::getParams(); its important params from config/params.php